# Function inside addEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

```
const bubbles = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble')

function filledBubble (event){
    event.classList.toggle("filled");
}

bubbles.forEach((bubble) => {
    bubble.addEventListener('click', filledBubble);
})
```

Hello everyone,

I was trying to apply an event to my bubbles. So when we click, it will change the color.
But somehow, I don't know why my function didn't work . Also, on the console, it showed no syntaxic error either.

Do you see any error in my code ?

The HTML code

```
<h3>Select</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bubble"></div>
        <div class="bubble"></div>
        <div class="bubble"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `event` value that is passed to your handler is not a DOM element; it's an event object. You can try `event.target.classList.toggle("filled")`

Comment: Thank you very much for your super quick answer. But I have already tried. It didn't work. I've added the HTML code, it may help.

Comment: As @Pointy mentioned, `event.target.classList.toggle` should work. Check this [JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ye8wv1sq/)

Comment: Ah ! It works !! I can see now where is my error come from !
thank you very much for making me the demonstration  
I woundn't have understood, if I hadn't seen your demonstration 

Thank you again !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the `event.target.classList.toggle("filled")` is the answer, but since you're saying it's not then you have the javascript initialization happening before the HTML has been rendered. In other words, put your javascript after your HTML.

OR, run the javascript initialzation after the page has loaded:

```
<head>
<script>

let bubbles

function initJS() {
  bubbles = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble');
  bubbles.forEach((bubble) => {
    bubble.addEventListener('click', filledBubble);
  });
}

function filledBubble (event){
  this.classList.toggle("filled");
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload='initJS()'>
...
<h3>Select</h3>
<div class="container">
    <div class="bubble"> bubble 1</div>
    <div class="bubble"> bubble 2</div>
    <div class="bubble"> bubble 3</div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use  **event.target** `event.target.classList.toggle("filled")`
or  **this** `this.classList.toggle("filled")`

demo:

```js
const bubbles = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble')

function filledBubble (event){
  this.classList.toggle("filled");
}

bubbles.forEach((bubble) => {
  bubble.addEventListener('click', filledBubble);
})
```

```css
.bubble { margin: .5em; cursor: pointer; }
.filled { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<h3>Select</h3>
<div class="container">
    <div class="bubble"> bubble 1</div>
    <div class="bubble"> bubble 2</div>
    <div class="bubble"> bubble 3</div>
 
</div>
```